# Using rails devise, empty password fields aren't present in debug(params)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords, parameters

I'm new to rails and devise, so I'm trying to understand what is going on. I am following the devise wiki for allowing users to edit their own password, found here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password.

What I find confusing is that even though I am using :validatable in my model, it seems that I am able to submit the form even if I leave password/password_confirmation blank, as long as I complete current_password. It seems this has something to do with the fact that in [validatable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb), that there is a validation for password only if !password.nil? [per line 54](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L54).

So I decided to look at debug(params) on form submission, and it seems indeed that if I leave the password/password_confirmation fields blank, then password/password_confirmation do not appear in the params hash at all (and though password.nil? is true?).

What I don't understand is why this happens? Even if I leave the password field blank, shouldn't password appear in params just like any other field, as "password" => ""? Since I'm using my own controller action to process the form, how is it that password is not in params?

Comment: How are you determining that the password and confirmation fields are not passed in the params?  Are you logging it?  I actually just threw together a barebones Rails app with Devise just to see if this happens, and for me it did not.  They're empty strings in the params, as you'd expect.

Comment: In the controller action found from devise's wiki page here ( https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password), I added this to the beginning of the update_password action:

`flash[:notice] = params[:user]`

When I leave the password/password_confirmation fields blank on the form, the flash notice simply states "{}". However, I do see in the server console that "password" => "[FILTERED]".

Comment: @numbers1311407 Based on what you wrote, I decided to try adding if statement to test if `params[:user][:password].nil?` on submission of a blank password field. You are right, the field is NOT nil, only blank. Guess now I'm confused as to why `flash[:notice] = params[:user]` returns {} only? Since password is blank, I would've thought that the devise's validatable [shown here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L33) would've caught the validation error on blank password submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update_with_password` method that is used on that wiki page is what's causing your confusion.  It deletes both `password` and `password_confirmation` from the params if they are blank, [as seen here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L59).

This seems like an oversight on the wiki page, as it's describing how to implement your own change password action.  This is definitely an issue in that case (submitting a "change password" form without filling out a password should probably fail).

Anyway, you could work around it, and still use the `update_with_password` method, just by checking to see if the password is blank beforehand, something like this (refactored as you like):

```
def update_password
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)

  if params[:user][:password].blank?
    @user.errors.add(:password, :blank)
    render "edit"
  elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    # Sign in the user by passing validation in case his password changed
    sign_in @user, :bypass => true
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really makes a lot of sense! I would upvote but it seems I can't yet.

I think I'll use conditional validation in my user model, along with attr_writer and a hidden field in my form, to trigger the blank password field validation. Something like `validates :password, :presence => true, :if => :should_validate_password?`. I'm thinking this may go better with the rails philosophy of skinny controllers, fat models?

Comment: Yeah I actually thought about suggesting the hidden field route but just wanted to be clear.  You're right, it is a better solution :-)